# AngularJS 2 Pagination Returns NaN onClick

Tags: angularjs, angular, meteor

I'm following this example here:

https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular2.0-socially/blob/master/manuals/views/step13.md

> [Step 13.11](https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular2.0-socially/blob/master/manuals/views/step13.md#step-1311-add-pagechange-event-binding): Add pageChange event binding

And pageChange, nothing happens. Using the console to debug the page number is being returned as `NaN`. If I hard code the page number there's no problem i.e. I can paginate. The `$event` is being passed as `NaN` (or `null` or `undefined` I guess).

**EDIT**

Code I'm using.

ng:

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="onPageChanged($event)"></pagination-controls>
```

*https://github.com/jessejamesrichard/shortshape/blob/master/client/imports/app/parties/parties-list.component.html (17)*

Calling:

```
onPageChanged(page: number): void {
  console.log(page);
  this.curPage.next(page);
}
```

*https://github.com/jessejamesrichard/shortshape/blob/master/client/imports/app/parties/parties-list.component.ts* (99)

I think the problem is isolated to `onPageChanged($event)`. Either `$event` is wrong, or typesetting is an issue, or I've totally messed something else up. Or a combination.

Comment: plz  share your code  plnkr or github link. Without that we can not solve your problem

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and eventually found out the problem was that I was missing the  `id` attribute on `<tr>` tag. having more than one table with pagination in my html page, I had to provide `id` for `<pagination-controls>` tags but I was missing to put it on `<tr>` as well.

here is what I got:

in my html:

```html
 <table>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let request of requests | 
      paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p2, id: 'history' };
          let i = index">
          <!--put your <td> tags here...-->
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<pagination-controls previousLabel="pre" 
nextLabel="next" (pageChange)="p2 = $event" maxSize="9" directionLinks="true" id="history"></pagination-controls>
```